# javascript overriding tick display value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am creating a chart very similar to below but would like to make following modifications:

http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_interactive_legends

data file found here: http://dimplejs.org/data/example_data.tsv

On y axis, if value = 50,000,000, Id like to display the tick mark as '50m +' instead of just '50m'.  I only want to do this for the max tick val.  Tried the following but this is not rendering:

```
 var y =  myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Value");
 y.text(function(d) {           
          if (d.var >= 50000000) {return "50 m +"}
           };
```

Comment: add `console.log(d.var);` before the if statement, see what's the console output.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because the number is treated as string try parsing it to int value like:

```
var y =  myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Sales Value");
y.text(function(d) {           
    var val = d.val.replace(/,/g, "");
    parseInt(val, 10);
    if (val >= 50000000) {
      return "50 m +";
    }
};
```

Comment: I fixed my original as suggested by Siraj and also added the missing parenthetical in the last line.  Still, not able to achieve the result looking for.  The console returns the error message:  "Uncaught TypeError: y.text is not a function"